# float left causes div to gain 'margin'

Tags: html, css

I have 5 divs in two wrapper divs and when I am assigning the float left attribute to the 5 dips they are gaining a 'top-margin'  of 5, as in they have a space between the top of the wrapper div and them. Here is My HTML and CSS

HTML:

```
<div class="headerMenuWrapper">
    <div class="menuOuterWrapper">
        <div class="menuInnerWrapper" id="menuWrapper">
            <div class="menuItem">Home</div>
            <div class="menuItem">About Us</div>
            <div class="menuItem">Products</div>
            <div class="menuItem">FAQ</div>
            <div class="menuItem">Contact Us</div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menuOuterWrapper{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
 }

 .menuInnerWrapper {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #327CF1;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000000;
  }

.menuItem {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #051625;
    float: left;
}

.headerMenuWrapper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 95%;
    height: 50%;
 }
```

Comment: May I suggest: if this is a main menu, using list items. Some examples of floating lists to make a menu can be seen here: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/

Comment: Where do you see the _magical_ 'top-margin' of 5? In Firebug? And have you tried to remove the box-shadow since it's the only thing with a 5px value in your styles?

Comment: I have solved the problem as I missed to assign a parent a float value (rather stupid of me) but still thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

**[Is this what you are looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/B2xCY/)**

[image]

You have a lot going on in your markup that shouldn't be.

I simplified everything for you by using:

- `nav`
- `ul`
- `li`

Instead of floats and margins, I used:

- `display: table`
- `display: table-cell`
- `text-align: center`

---

### HTML

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li>Products</li>
        <li>FAQ</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

---

### CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
#menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu > ul {
    display: table;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000000;
    background: #327CF1;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu ul > li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
}
#menu > ul > li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Resetting Browser-Style Defaults for Elements

shorthand for you

- {
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px;
      }

margin: auto tells to browser automatically calculate margin
example of reset styles here http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/12/reset-styles/